# Css connecting dots creating square

Tags: css, geometry

how can I create square using css with just four lines connecting in four points.
I need to have each side different colour sth like this 
[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:
html:

```
<div class='holder'>
  <div class="square">
    <div class='content'>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.holder {
  width: 40px;//or a percentage it will still be a square
 }

.square {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 3px solid red;
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  border-right: 3px solid yellow;
  border-left: 3px solid green;
}

.square:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Reink is there a way how to connect two points with a line? Like [20px,30px] and [60px,80px]

Comment: Is it possible to do it purely with CSS?

Comment: Not as a coordinate system, you could play with div (absolute) positions